# How to enable X-Forwarded-For (XFF) Header in Joomla 3.10.x

Tags: php, server, joomla3.0, x-forwarded-for

I want to enable XFF Header for my Joomla! site. There is no specific guide in Joomla Support site. I have tried the Joomla System->Global Configuration->Server and Under Proxy Settings, Enable the "Behind Load Balancer", but not working. Is there any another method to enable XFF Header.